# Reloading a Chrome extension content script execution environment

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I’d like to mimic the effect of `window.location.reload()`, but only for the “isolated world” which my content script is running in. That is, remove all existing JS, particularly callbacks and event bindings. Is there a nice way to do this?

Note: `chrome.runtime.reload()` doesn’t work for this; it has the effect of reloading the extension and the background script, but it does not reload existing content scripts until the user refreshes.

Answer (score 7):

As far as I can tell, there's no automatic way to re-inject content scripts, for example during an extension update. What you can do is to find all tabs whose url matches the pattern you need, and programmatically re-inject the content scripts using [`chrome.tabs.executeScript`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-executeScript).

Note that this method requires to add a permission for the same URL pattern as the one used by your content script.

**Manifest.json:**

```
"content_scripts":    
[
    {
        "matches": [ "http://*.google.com/*" ],
        "js": [ "content_script.js" ]
    }
], 
"permissions":        
[ 
    "tabs", "http://*.google.com/*"
]
```

**Background.js:**

```
chrome.runtime.reload();
chrome.tabs.query({ url: "http://*.google.com/*" }, function(tabs)
{
    for(var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++)
    {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[i].id, { file: "content_script.js" }, function() {});
    }
});
```

Comment: The problem is that this leaves the existing context untouched. If I start a setInterval in one executeScript it'll still be running after the next executeScript.

Comment: When the second content script is executed a second time, you have access to the previous variables, so you could reset everything.

Comment: @Metoule You do not have access to previous variables when injecting after reloading the extension from `chrome://extension`. Have you tested this?